# getting a render problem in the xml file and theres a compatibility error in the gradle versions

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop a location map for uni. The app itself works on my phone but I can't edit the XML file or preview it

I've already enabled virtualisation and have an i5 processor. I believe the issue lies in the Gradle build but don't know how to fix it.

```groovy
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

And the error message:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible
```

It looks like the `media-compat:26` should be updated to a newer version but I can't find the code for it or the library and don't know how to download the library. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `targetSdkVersion` to `28`?

Comment: Yes it is set at 28

Answer (score 0):

Try change implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compileSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 26
```

All libraries must have the same version, in the case it looks like a conflict between com.google.android.gms: play-services-maps: 16.0.0 and implementation 'com.android.support: appcompat-v7:28.0.0'.

If you are using compileSdkVersion 28 try to find the latest version of the libraries in the maven repository.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0

Comment: If it is possible please provide some more details about how can this will solve OP's problem, including a documentation or a better explanation of the solution.

Comment: tried it it didnt work. i also deleted everything uninstaled android studio. Reinstalled it and set up a google maps activity and the same error pops up striaght away without any code in java being written in. SO there has to be an issue with the libraries

Comment: This is a dependency version conflict.

Comment: I think this dependency is not compatible with compileSdkVersion 28 and appcompat-v7:28.0.0. I used version 26 and it worked. I had the same problem with the .google.firebase: firebase-database: 16.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to **28**. Because all your support libraries must match to your compileSdkVersion's root number. And, if you add more support libraries like- `support:design` or `support:recyclerview-v7`, you must add the same version (here you used 28.0.0). Otherwise, the app can crash at the runtime for mismatching. The full Google repository for android is here http://maven.google.com.
 
To know more about gradle dependencies of android, please go to official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/). For google play service API configuration, go to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: this was done still the same error. uninstalled everything and reinstalled it all again and without even writing any code i got the same error       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: Open a new android studio project and run it to check all things are OK within a new project. Uninstall android studio is not a solution at all.